# react-native componentDidMount to fetch from server

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("props");
    this.state = {
        userId : "12345",
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
    Actions.getProductDetails({userId:"123456"});
    Actions.getProductDetails.completed.listen(this.gotProductDetails.bind(this));
    Actions.cancelOrder.completed.listen(this.cancelOrderCompleted.bind(this));       
}
gotProductDetails(data) {
    console.log("gotProductDetails");  
}
goBack(data) {
    console.log("justgoback");
    this.props.back();
}
cancelProduct() {
    console.log("SDsadsadsad");
    Actions.cancelOrder({
        orderId:this.state.order.id,
        canelMsg:this.state.selectedReason,
        userId:this.state.userId
    });
}
cancelOrderCompleted(data) {
    console.log("cancelOrderCompleted");
    this.goBack();
}
```

> My issue is some functions are mounting twice whenever I change the
>   route and revisit this route again I would show you console.log here

**This is for first time I come to this route:**

```
props
cancelOrder.js:190 componentDidMount
cancelOrder.js:197 gotProductDetails
```

Now I will do cancelProduct call and log will be

```
SDsadsadsad
cancelOrder.js:221 cancelOrderCompleted
cancelOrder.js:210 justgoback
```

**This is for second time i.e, I will go back from this route and revisit:**

```
props
cancelOrder.js:190 componentDidMount
cancelOrder.js:197 gotProductDetails
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the cancelOrder component.
cancelOrder.js:197 gotProductDetails
```

Now I will do cancelProduct call and log will be

```
SDsadsadsad
cancelOrder.js:221 cancelOrderCompleted
cancelOrder.js:210 justgoback
cancelOrder.js:221 cancelOrderCompleted
cancelOrder.js:210 justgoback
```

In the above log you can see that for the second time `line number 197 221 210 executed twice with the error` I was not able to solve

I'm using react `navigator` for [route](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#navigator)

I checked in release version also, but it is having same error it was told in one Github issue, but was not able to find now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you run this line

```js
Actions.cancelOrder.completed.listen(this.cancelOrderCompleted.bind(this));
```

The `listen` method gets a new function instance every time it runs, so if this page was mounted twice in the app's lifecycle, the `cancelOrderCompleted` would run twice and one of them probably in an unmounted component which is bad.

Generally I would advise that your `getProductDetails` would return a `Promise`. If you don't want to do that, make sure you remove the listeners when your component is unmounted.

And be aware that `cancelOrderCompleted.bind(this)` creates a new delegate instance that you can't recreate when stopping the listener. Unless you keep it in a data member.

Edit:

Code example -

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("props");
    this.state={
        userId : "12345",
    }

    this.getProductDetailsBound = this.gotProductDetails.bind(this);
    this.cancelOrderCompletedBound = this.cancelOrderCompleted.bind(this);
}
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount")

    // Listen before you call getProductDetails, not after
    Actions.getProductDetails.completed.listen(this.getProductDetailsBound);        
    Actions.cancelOrder.completed.listen(this.cancelOrderCompletedBound);  

    Actions.getProductDetails({userId:"123456"});  
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    Actions.getProductDetails.completed.stopListening(this.getProductDetailsBound);        
    Actions.cancelOrder.completed.stopListening(this.cancelOrderCompletedBound);  
}
```

Comment: what you said is 100% correct cancelOrderCompleted creates new instance every time the route is pushed...but my concern is if i require the response which i got from cancelorder how do i get and work on it.......?

Comment: It was tough for me to understand what you were telling since i was not aware of much of this concepts thankyou...

Comment: really sorry to bother you i did es6 based implementations also still it persists

Comment: Actions.cancelOrder.completed.listen((data) => {
            console.log("cancelOrderCompleted")
            ToastAndroid.show(data.msg, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
            this.props.back()
        }); I did like this in es6 but still no use

Comment: I tried this also https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/1138 no use

Comment: solved it thank you very much for your answer..since i was using reflux https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs/issues/225#issuecomment-120160981

Comment: If i change that bind to contructor also it has some issue the problem is with with reflux so i had to do like this https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs/issues/225#issuecomment-120037469

Comment: Sorry mate I didn't really get the alternative solution here. You just need the same delegate reference on your startListening and your stopListening. How is that problematic to do?